How to create a Shopify App Extension / Embed to render custom content in existing liquid components?
I want to develop a Shopify app extension/embed for merchants to display "Review Stars" on every product component, including the home page, collections, and search results.
How can I create an app embed that automatically identifies the specific Liquid files for product components in a Shopify store and injects my review stars code into them? Are there alternative or better methods to implement this feature?
